# Is there a way to execute and read data from Chrome's console using python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find a way to read information from Chromes console. The website that I am using is `chrome://Dino`. In the console, the main commands I want to execute and read are `Runner().crashed`, `Runner().horizon.runningTime`, `Runner().horizon.obstacles`, and some other simple commands.

I have tried using Selenium, but I couldn't get it to work, and after googling for a while, I couldn't find a solution. Do you know how I might be able to do this?

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my answer? I'm curious to see the outcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use Selenium (with C#) to get all the listed information. 
['How to output result of Javascript execution to console?'](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11540/how-to-output-result-of-javascript-execution-to-console) gave me a hint.

```
// initialize the ChromeDriver, and get the jsExecutor
// This step may be different for Python
var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
var jSExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)chromeDriver;

// navigate to the page
chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://dino");

// get the values, using js command
var crashed = jSExecutor.ExecuteScript("return Runner().crashed");
var runningTime = jSExecutor.ExecuteScript("return Runner().horizon.runningTime");
var obstcles = jSExecutor.ExecuteScript("return Runner().horizon.obstacles");

// print the values
Console.WriteLine($"{crashed}, {runningTime}, {obstcles}");
```

One should be able to use [driver.execute_script](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=javascript#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) in Python to do the same.

```py
crashed = driver.execute_script('return Runner().crashed')
runningTime = driver.execute_script('return Runner().horizon.runningTime')
obstcles = driver.execute_script('return Runner().horizon.obstacles')
```